# Does $(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2 \le c\big((x-y)^2+(xy-1)^2\big) $ hold?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, polynomials, symmetry, symmetric-polynomials

Does there exist a positive constant $c>0$ such that
$$(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2 \le c\big((x-y)^2+(xy-1)^2\big) \tag{1}$$

holds for any nonnegative $x,y$?

**Let me add some context for this question:**

The motivation comes from the case were $x,y$ are interpreted as singular values of a $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$ with nonnegative determinant. Then $f(x,y)=(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2=\operatorname{dist}^2(A,\operatorname{SO}(2))$.

I am interested in bounding $\operatorname{dist}^2(A,\operatorname{SO}(2))$ from above by a sum of two terms: a term which penalizes deviations of $A$ from being area-preserving, and a term $\operatorname{dist}^2(A,\operatorname{CO}(2))$, which penalizes deviations from being conformal. (Here $\operatorname{CO}(2)=R^{+}\operatorname{SO}(2)$ is the group of conformal matrices).

In an answer to this [previous question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3796270/bounding-a-polynomial-by-a-sum-with-certain-properties), the following bound was proved:
$$
 (x-1)^2+(y-1)^2 \le |x-y||x+y| + 2|xy-1|.
$$

While this is close to what I had in mind, the term $|x-y||x+y|$ can be large even when $x,y$ become very close. In fact, [one can prove that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2375840/closest-conformal-matrix-to-a-given-matrix) $\operatorname{dist}^2(A,\operatorname{CO}(2))=\frac{1}{2}(\sigma_1(A)-\sigma_2(A))^2$, so this is the reason for asking about the specific bound $(1)$. (The term $(x-y)^2$ corresponds to $\operatorname{dist}^2(A,\operatorname{CO}(2))$).

Comment: You have asked many good questions earlier but this one is out of context.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You are right. I appreciate that you commented here and not just downvoted (if you did so). Anyway, I agree that "being a good contributor" for the site and community should not give you immunity and free ability to post bad questions. To be honest, I wasn't sure that the specific context would interest too many people. But this might be just an excuse for laziness on my part. Anyway, I have now added some context. I am still not sure this question is really "of broad enough interest" to the community, but I guess we shall see:). Thanks again for contacting me.

Comment: I did not vote for closure.  I saw two votes for closure and thought I should help you by suggesting that  you  provide some context (so that the question does not  get closed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x=y=0,$ we get $c \geqslant 2.$

For $c =2,$ inequality become
$$(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2 \leqslant 2\big((x-y)^2+(xy-1)^2\big),$$
equivalent to
$$2x^2y^2+x^2+y^2+2(x+y) \geqslant 8xy.$$
Using the AM-GM inequality, we have
$$2x^2y^2+x^2+y^2+2(x+y) \geqslant 8\sqrt[8]{(x^2y^2)^2 \cdot x^2 \cdot y^2 \cdot (xy)^2}=8xy.$$
So, your inequality holds for all $c \geqslant 2.$